# How to make a smooth jump with a rigidbody in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a character in unity controlled by a rigidbody. However, the jump is one jerky movement not a smooth motion. Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Rigidbody component attached to the player")]
    public Rigidbody rb;

    private float movementX;
    private float movementY;
    private float gravity = -9.81f;
    private float speedX = 10;
    private float speedY = 1000;
    private float speedZ = 5;
    private bool isJumping = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

        movementX = movementVector.x;
        movementY = movementVector.y;
    }

    void OnJump()
    {
        //isJumping = true;
        Vector3 movementVelocity = new Vector3();
        movementVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(speedY * -3.0f * gravity);
        movementVelocity.y *= 100;
        rb.AddForce(movementVelocity, ForceMode.Force);
        //isJumping = false;
    }

    void CalculateMovement()
    {
        Vector3 movementVelocity = new Vector3(movementX * speedX, 0, speedZ);
        rb.velocity = movementVelocity;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CalculateMovement();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get a smooth jump with a rigidbody?

I have tried all the different options for `ForceMode` and tried updating the `Rigidbody.velocity` characteristic, both at the same time and separately to the movement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AddForce(), thats easier and always works as well. Your code will give a smooth jump too, but AddForce() is more about Unity physics.

Answer (score 0):

For smooth transitions you would ordinarily use interpolation, or lerping.
Interpolation allows you to smooth out the effect of running physics at a fixed frame rate.
Interpolate is an Rigidbody' s property and is is turned off by default, try to enabled it.

Comment: I tried turning on interlopation but that didn't make any difference to the smoothness of the jump. It's still just one jerky movement not a smooth movement.

Comment: You're getting something wrong in physics. Try the jump as an impulse, ForceMode.Force in ForceMode.Impulse and insert it in the update and not in the fixedUpdate, with interpolate checked

Comment: That's still just one jerk not a smooth movement. Putting it in Update() just made it frame rate dependant.